# priority queue using class object

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a priority queue with Student class. 
I overloaded operator< function which compare student id of two objects of Student class, but my code does not work. 
Could you give me any advice?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Student {
public:
    string name;
    int id;

    Student(string str, int n) {
        this->name = str;
        this->id = n;
    };

};


bool operator<(const Student& a, const Student& b) {
    return a.id < b.id;
}


int main() {
    priority_queue<Student> pq;
    pq.push(Student("Miria", 1));
    pq.push(Student("Ken", 2));
    pq.push(Student("Bob", 3));

    while (!pq.empty()) {
        cout << pq.top() << endl;
        pq.pop();
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you say "my code does not work", what do you mean by that? What is the actual and expected output of your program? Please take some time to read [ask] as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: You don't have string representation of the `Student` class. Print it like `cout << pq.top().name << " " << pq.top().id << endl;` or add conversion to string.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. I totally forgot to put the code what I want to show. Now it works well!

Answer (score 1):

I am kind of unaware what an "My code does not work seems", although it seems to me that you are not printing the objects in the `priority_queue` correctly.

The appropriate way of printing them will be by using the object's properties or using a string representation operator overload. Let me give you an example of how the simpler version of the code would look like by using your code:

```cpp
cout << pq.top().name << "'s id is: " << pq.top().id << endl;
```

The reason your code is not working is because you are lacking the output operator overload. You are not able to compile the program itself if you are lacking this operator.

The former spoken of is done the foreshown code down below:

```cpp
friend ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Student& obj) {
    return output << obj.name << "'s id is: " << obj.id << endl;
};
```

This way you will be able to use the `pq.top()` function in the `cout` stream:

```cpp
cout << pq.top();
```

I hope this is what you expect and if you want to make it in increase order like Java you can use priority_queue.

The expected output as the question is described should be:

```
Bob's id is: 3
Ken's id is: 2
Miria's id is: 1
```